# program has to end but won't stop

Tags: python, math, division

I am trying to build a program that controls if a integer is divisible by '9'. I have this for the code.

```
import sys
a=int(sys.argv[1])

if a < 1:
    pos_num= a*(-1)
    b=map(int, str(pos_num))
    c=sum(b)
    print(c)
else:
    b=map(int, str(a))
    c=sum(b)
    print(c)


if c > 10:
    d=map(int, str(c))
    d1= sum(d)
    print(d1)
elif c==9:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")


if d1 > 10:
    e=map(int, str(d1))
    e1= sum(e)
    print(e1)
elif c==9:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")


if e1 > 10:
    f=map(int, str(e1))
    f1= sum(f)
    print(d1)
elif c==9:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

The problem is that when the integer isn't big for example '27', the program will display that it doesn't have a value for 'd1'. Does someone have a suggestion?

Comment: `print(a % 9 == 0)`?

Answer (score 5):

Replace the entire program with

```
import sys
print("yes" if ((int(sys.argv[1]) % 9)==0) else "no")
```

Comment: Of course, the error you are seeing is because d1 is only defined when c > 10.

Comment: @Jaques F. I always say what is the least amount of code to do this with and if what you can come up with is unreasonably long then there probably is a shorter way and faster way to do it, after all thats what computers are for.